# How to define typemap(in) and typemap(out) for const_iterator * in swig/python?

Tags: c++, python, swig

I'd like to let swig know about the type of my const_iterators so that it can GC them and get rid of this error:

```
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'MyClass::const_iterator *', no destructor found
```

I can't really figure out how I'm supposed to go from python to C++ and then back using the typemap(in) and typemap(out) directives. I can use these objects fine inside of python, but I guess I'm missing something essential about pointers swig and the C-API.

Comment: is `MyClass::const_iterator` a "standard" iterator? If it it then you can probably use `pyiterators.swg`. If not `SwigPyIterator_T` can be used as a starting point.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I can answer if you add some more details, but without that it's hard to do more than just guess